# SSE 2 and above - Why floating point data types store only 2 floating point numbers

Tags: x86, sse, simd, sse2

I am attempting to optimise my code using SSE intrinsic functions. After going through the documentation, I see that there is `__m128` datatype in SSE for floating point variables, capable of storing 4 float numbers. There is a `__m128d` in SSE2 capable of only storing 2 floating point numbers? What is the difference between these variables? Isn't SSE2 supposed to be faster than SSE?

Comment: *Isn't SSE2 supposed to be faster than SSE?*  No, it's supposed to provide instructions for integer and double precision float, instead of just single-precision float.  See the SSE tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info.  Perhaps you're looking for AVX, which provides 256b registers: 8 `float` or 4 `double`.

Comment: Oh. I confused them all to be different instruction sets! Got it. Thanks.

Comment: They are different instruction sets.  Pentium III only supported SSE, so could only use the XMM registers for scalar or packed single precision, not integer or double.  SSE2 was added later.

Comment: But SSE2 provides support only for double datatype. If I want to use float datatype, I need to use __m128. So SSE2 is kind of an extension to SSE right? In the sense that it only adds those functions and datatypes that aren't available in SSE.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Most later extensions (SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1) added some instructions for each existing data type. (some `pxxx` integer, some `xxxps` float, some `xxxpd` instructions.  See https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/. which lists extension groups for each instruction.)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info

Comment: You might find [this blog post series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/09/11/directxmath-sse-sse2-and-arm-neon/) useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSE instructions use 128 bit registers.

A `float` uses 4 bytes = 32 bits -> hence you can store 4 floats (4*32=128), these are the `__m128`.

A `double` uses 8 bytes = 64 bits -> hence you can store 2 doubles (2*64=128), these are the `__m128d`.

-> Further information https://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/cpp-getting-started-with-sse/